# Python input() for ENTER

Tags: python, input, enter

What is input for ENTER key?

```
tf_end=str(input("TF end: "))
tfend={"":7,'1':0,'2':1,'3':2,'5':3,'10':4,'15':5,'30':6,'1h':7}
while not any(x in tfend.keys() for x in tf_end):  
      tf_end=str(input("TF end: "))
```

Because I do above logic but "" is not equal to ENTER (cannot escape while loop).
How to escape this while loop by using ENTER key?

Comment: Hint: `list('') == []` and `any([]) == False`

Comment: Note, `str(input(...))` is redundant. `input` **always** returns a `str`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga might be a bad habit left over from Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

When you only press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `input()` returns the empty string. Your code doesn't work because `any()` of an empty iterable is `False`. Also note that it only happens to work for the multi-character keys because their first characters are also keys.

It looks like you're using `any()` by accident. Use `if not tf_end in tfend` instead.

I would make a few other changes too:

```
tfend = {'': 7, '1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 2, '5': 3, '10': 4, '15': 5, '30': 6, '1h': 7}
tf_end = None  # Sentinel value instead of a duplicate `input()`
while not tf_end in tfend:  # `.keys()` is implied
    tf_end = input("TF end: ")  # `str()` is redundant
```

Comment: Cannot work..how to declare ENTER into list?

Comment: @uyin What do you mean?